# Is this the right connotation for the word across in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, connotations

This is the context, from [an English translation](https://etc.usf.edu/lit2go/182/crime-and-punishment/3393/part-1-chapter-2/) of Dostoyevsky's Crime and Punishment.

> A very poor-looking room about ten paces long was lighted up by a candle-end; the whole of it was visible from the entrance. It was all in disorder, littered up with rags of all
> sorts, especially children’s garments. **Across the furthest
> corner was stretched a ragged sheet.** Behind it probably was the bed.

According to TFD across is a preposition meaning:
3. From one side of to the other: a bridge across a river.

Does this mean that the sheet was stretched from one to the other wall which create that corner as if the sheet was the base(or a hypotenuse) of a triangle and the walls were the sides?

Comment: Yes, that is how I would picture it.

Comment: Agree with @DanielRoseman. The passage reads as if the sheet is arranged as a curtain to separate the (probable) bed in the corner from the rest of the room.

Comment: muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is how I would picture it.

The passage reads as if the sheet is arranged as a curtain to separate the (probable) bed in the corner from the rest of the room.

Comment: converting comments to answer